# 'Query Performance plan' query in singlestore

Tags: query-performance, execution-plan, singlestore

when I go to memsqlOps > Explore > Query. I’m able to see query performance and active long running queries. What table or tables can I select from to get that same information?

Answer (score 1):

Try using below query, select desired columns and filter out "query" from activity column for which you want to have performance and time stats.

```
select * 
     from information_schema.mv_activities_extended a
LEFT JOIN information_schema.mv_queries q
      ON a.ACTIVITY_NAME = q.ACTIVITY_NAME
where 
     a.activity_type = 'Query' and a.database_name is NOT NULL;
```